# Java Function conversion to Kotlin fails

Tags: java, kotlin

Trying to convert some java code to kotlin, given the following method

```
public class Option<T> {

  public <U> Option<U> map(Function<T, U> mapper) {
    throw new IllegalStateException();
  }
}
```

kotlin conversion will give this

[image]

I cannot understand whats the problem here, and how do i create equivalent method in kotlin? (thats the `java.util.Function`)

P.S. could not come up with some better question summary... feel free to change.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To use `java.util.function.Function`, you have to import it explicitly:

```
import java.util.function.Function
```

That's because by default `Function` is resolved to [`kotlin.Function`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-function.html).

But there are [function types](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#function-types) in Kotlin, and more idiomatic implementation would be

```
fun <U> map(mapper: (T) -> U): Option<U> {
    // ...
}
```